# Probability of at least N events occuring

Tags: probability

I have a series of N events, *each with its own probability of occurring*. How would I calculate the probability that at least M of the N events actually do occur?

I think this is conditional, in that getting at least M occurrences depends on getting at least M-1 occurrences. Past that I'm getting stuck.

Comment: What do you know about your events? If they're independent you can calculate the probability exactly. If not you can only estimate it.

Comment: @Tim: I guess we have a silent assumption here about independence, sort of like an extension of Binomial distribution

Comment: Unfortunately although you can calculate it there won't be an easy formula.  You just have to multiply the probabilities of every possible combination of more than $M$ events and add them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider that we have four independent events A,B,C,D each with probability Pa,Pb,Pc,Pd associated with it.
Now we have to find the probability of at least two events occurring.

First we find the probability of exactly two events occurring.

These two events can be AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD.

event space = {AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD, }

Since all these events are mutually exclusive.

Probability of any one them occurring is Sum of all probabilities in the events space.

P(AB) = Pa * Pb * (1-Pc) * (1-Pd)

P(AC) = Pa * (1-Pb) * Pc * (1-Pd)

P(AD) = Pa * (1-Pb) * (1-Pc) * Pd

P(BC) = (1-Pa) * Pb * Pc * (1-Pd)

P(BD) = (1-Pa) * Pb * (1-Pc) * Pd

P(CD) = (1-Pa) * (1-Pb) * Pc * Pd

After that we can sum all these to get the probability of Two events occurring. In a similar way we can calculate probability of Three and Four events occurring.

Final probability = Prob(Two_events) + Prob(Three_events) + Prob(Four_events)

However I am unable to generalize for at least M events out of N.

I hope it will shed more light on your problem.

Comment: That's where the fun starts, because you don't care which $k$ events happen, so if say $k=2$ you need to account for $\binom{n}{2}$ ways of doing so

Comment: @Alex that is why this is so hard to generalize

Comment: That's precisely the description I needed and exactly the horrifying complexity I hoped it wouldn't lead to. Here's hoping I can code up a decent calculator!

Comment: Nasty as all hell, but I got my numbers crunched. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: @Corv: if you solved it, you can write your solution as an answer to your own question, so we all can know it.

Answer (score 5):

For any future visitors, the expression given for the probability of at least $m$ out of $n$ events $(A_1, \ldots ,A_n)$ in *An Introduction to Probability* by William Feller is this:

$$P_m = S_m - \binom{m}{1}S_{m+1}+\binom{m+1}{2}S_{m+2}-\ldots\pm\binom{n-1}{m-1}S_n$$

where $$\displaystyle S_k = \sum_{1\leq i_1< i_2\ldots< i_k\leq n}P(A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap\ldots \cap A_{i_k})$$

It's certainly not pretty, but it is general.

It is proved by finding the expression for exactly $m$ events and then adding the expressions from $m$ to all $n$ using induction.

Comment: Hi, how to you expand the summation? $$\displaystyle S_k = \sum_{1\leq i_1< i_2\ldots< i_k\leq n}P(A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap\ldots \cap A_{i_k})$$ Can you do a simple example expansion of where m=2 and n=3. Or provide me with some key words to find another thread. I have just never seen a summation with all those greater than signs and no value at the top.

Comment: The summation notation means to add all terms with particular values of $i_1, i_2, ..., i_k$ which satisfy the inequalities at the bottom. So if $n=3$ and $k=2$,
$$S_2 = P(A_1\cap A_2) + P(A_2\cap A_3) + P(A_1\cap A_3),$$
because the only values for $(i_1, i_2)$ that satisfy the inequalities are $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$ and $(1,3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Per Alex's suggestion, here's the Lua script I used to solve my problem. It does take a long while, and don't ignore the optimization suggestion if it's relevant!

```
--[[
    Lua script to calculate the odds that N of M events, each with its own probability of occuring, actually occur.

    numEvents: M, the total number of events in the chain
    sucessChances: the probabilities of each event, in order
    targetNumSuccesses: N, the minimum number of successes we'd like to see

    If targetNumSuccesses is less than half of numEvents, this could be optimized by finding event chains with exactly numEvent successes, rather than failures.
    The optimization would probably save you several lengthy iterations, especially if targetNumSuccesses is very small.
    This is left as an exercise for the reader.
--]]

local numEvents = 30
local targetNumSuccesses = 16
local successChances = {}
for i=1, numEvents do
    -- Insert code to calculate your event probabilities here!
    local someValue

    successChances[i] = someValue
end

-- Establish a failure table of all events failing to occur
local failureTable = {}
local function resetFailureTable()
    for i=1, numEvents do
        failureTable[i] = false
    end
end

-- This is a helper function to work through the possibile permutations of events.
local function reverseSubList(list, front, back)
    if front > back then
        front, back = back, front
    end

    local swaps = (back - front)/2
    for i = 0, swaps do
        list[front+i], list[back-i] = list[back-i], list[front+i]
    end
end

local numEventProbability = 0
local totalProbability = 0
local exhausted = false

--[[
    Start iterating through the possible series of events.

    The outer loop creates an event chain with exactly numEvent *failures*.
    The inner loop:
        calculates the probability of that event chain
        adds it to a running total
        finds the next event chain with the same number of failures
    Once all chains with exactly numEvent failures have been calculated:
        numEvent is "exhausted"
        the total probability of all chains with exactly numEvent failures is printed
        that value is added to the running total probability
--]]
for numEvents = 1,(numEvents - targetNumSuccesses) do
    -- Fill the failureTable with an appropriate number of hits.
    resetFailureTable()
    for i = 1, numEvents do
        failureTable[i] = true
    end

    -- This is already the base permutation of the failureTable, so:
    while not exhausted do
        local eventChainProbability = 1
        for subEvent = 1, numEvents do
            if failureTable[subEvent] then
                eventChainProbability = eventChainProbability*(1-successChances[subEvent])
            else
                eventChainProbability = eventChainProbability*(successChances[subEvent])
            end
        end
        numEventProbability = numEventProbability + eventChainProbability

        -- Get the next permutation of the failureTable
        for i = 30,1,-1 do
            if failureTable[i] == true and failureTable[i+1] == false then
                local rightmost
                for j=30,1,-1 do if failureTable[j] == false then rightmost = j break end end
                failureTable[i] = false
                failureTable[rightmost] = true
                reverseSubList(failureTable, i+1, 30)
                break
            elseif i == 1 then
                exhausted = true
            end
        end
    end
    exhausted = false
    print(string.format("Odds of being exactly %d failures: %.2f", numEvents, numEventProbability))
    totalProbability = totalProbability + numEventProbability
    numEventProbability = 0
end

print("Odds of at least %d successes: %f", targetNumSuccesses, 1-totalProbability)
local a = io.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this question - like I did - and wants to learn more about the problem:

If the $N$ events are independent and non-identical (as suggested by "*each with its own probability of occurring*" from the question), then the probability of getting $M$ or more successes follows a [Poisson-binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution). The answer given by zer0cube is correct and Milind Hegde posted the general case. A closed-form variation of the Probability Mass Function (PMF) - the probability that exactly $M$ trials occur - was found by [Fernandez & Williams (2010)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5461658) (and can be found on the linked wiki page). To find the probability that $M$ *or more* events occur, then you would sum the PMF for $k$ successes from $k = M, M+1, \dots N$.