# Probability that any $n$ independent events occur

Tags: probability, independence

Say there are *n* independent events, each with a probability *p* of occurring. What is the probability that *any* of these events occur?

My guess is that the probability is

$$ P(any) = p(1) + p(2) + p(3)+... + p(n)$$
$$ P(any) = p + p^2 + p^3 +... + p^n$$
$$ P(any) = \sum_{i=1}^n p^i$$

Does this sum have another form that can be computed easily? For example, if $n=800$, I don't want to actually calculate all $800$ terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 2 events $A$ and $B$ are independent if

$$P(A)P(B) = P(A \cap B)$$

- 3 events $A,B,C$ are independent if

$$P(A)P(B) = P(A \cap B)$$
$$P(A)P(C) = P(A \cap C)$$
$$P(C)P(B) = P(C \cap B)$$
$$P(A)P(B)P(C) = P(A \cap B \cap C)$$

If we have the 1st 3 but not the 4th, then $A,B,C$ are not independent, but they are pairwise independent.

- So what's the probability of $A \cup B \cup C$? The probability at least one occurs is equal to 1 - the probability that none occur.

$$P(A \cup B \cup C) = 1-P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c)$$

$$ = 1-P(A^c)P(B^c)P(C^c) \tag{***}$$

$$ = 1-(1-P(A))(1-P(B))(1-P(C))$$

$$ = 1-(1-p)(1-p)(1-p)$$

$$ = 1-(1-p)^3$$

What just happened at $(***)$?

Actually, if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then

1. $A^C$ and $B^C$ are independent
2. $A^C$ and $B$ are independent
3. $A$ and $B^C$ are independent

Similarly, if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are independent, then $A^C, B^C, C^C$ are independent.

Hence

$$P(A^C)P(B^C) = P(A^C \cap B^C)$$
$$P(A^C)P(C^C) = P(A^C \cap C^C)$$
$$P(C^C)P(B^C) = P(C^C \cap B^C)$$
$$P(A^C)P(B^C)P(C^C) = P(A^C \cap B^C \cap C^C)$$

The last part is what is used to justify $(***)$.

Now finally how about for $n$ independent events $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$?

$$P(A_1 \cup ... \cup A_n) = 1-P(A_1^c \cap ... \cap A_n^c)$$

$$ = 1-P(A_1^c)...P(A_n^c)$$

$$ = 1-(1-P(A_1))...(1-P(A_n))$$

$$ = 1-(1-p)...(1-p)$$

$$ = 1-(1-p)^n$$

---

It looks like you meant to compute probability exactly 1 occurs, probability exactly 2 events occur, etc.

To compute probability exactly 1 occurs:

$$P(A_1 \cap A_2^C \cap ... \cap A_n^C) = P(A_1)P(A_2^C) ... P(A_n^C) = p(1-p)^{n-1}$$

Similarly, we have

$$P(A_1^C \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n^C) = p(1-p)^{n-1}$$

etc

Thus we have

Probability exactly 1 occurs = $np(1-p)^{n-1}$, not $p$

Note that

$$np(1-p)^{n-1} = \binom{n}{1}p^1(1-p)^{n-1}$$

Similarly, probability exactly 2 occur = $\binom{n}{2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2}$

Thus probability any $n$ occur =

$$\binom{n}{1}p^1(1-p)^{n-1} + \binom{n}{2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2} + ... + \binom{n}{n}p^n(1-p)^{n-n}$$

By binomial expansion, we have:

$$= ((p) + (1-p))^n - \binom{n}{0}p^0(1-p)^{n-0} = 1 - (1-p)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use $1-\prod_k(1-p_k)$. The part after the $1-$ finds the probability that none of the events happen, and the $1-$ part finds the opposite of that, i.e. the probability that at least one of these events happen.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$
So if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

This is because more than one of the events can also happen together.
For three events:
$$P (A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A ∩ B) - P(A ∩ C) - P(B ∩ C) + P(A ∩ B ∩ C)$$
and similarly for more events.

So the correct way to deal with this situation is to calculate the complimentary probability $$P(\overline{A\cup B \cdots})=P(\bar{A}\cap \bar{B} \cap \cdots )$$ and then your desired probability is
$$P(\text{any event})=1-P(\bar{A}\cap \bar{B} \cap \cdots )$$ 
So by independence,
$$P(\text{any event})=1-P(\bar A)P(\bar B)\cdots=1-\big[(1-P(A))(1-P( B))\cdots\big]$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The probability that *any* occur is equal to one minus the probability that *none* occur.

The probability that no events occur is equal to the probability that the first doesn't occur AND the second doesn't occur AND ... AND the $n^{th}$ doesn't occur.

Recall the "and rule" of probability; the probability of $A$ and $B$ is equal to the probability of $A$ multiplied by the probability of $B$. (this is for independent events)

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, it is easier to just compute the complementary event: `none of the n events occur`. The probability of none happening is $(1-p)^n$, so the probability that any of $n$ independent events occur is  $1-(1-p)^n$

But I started this answer because I wanted to expand on the (more difficult) way you chose to compute this probability. Your method of computing the probability for exactly one event happening, exactly 2 events happening and so on, and adding them all together is correct. However the way you compute these probabilities is not correct.

Let's say you are having $n$ events (all independent and equiprobable) and you want to compute the probability that *exactly one* is happening. To approach the problem you can think about one *specific* event happening, say the first one. What's the probability of this? It is $p\times (1-p)^{n-1}$. Or in other words, the probability of the first one happening times the probabilities of the rest not happening. If we are looking for *any* one event (exactly one event) then we have to consider all other single events happening (the 2nd, 3rd,..nth).
These have the same probability $p\times (1-p)^{n-1}$ and we have $n$ of them.

How about exactly two events happening? If we take two *specific* events, then the probability is $p^2\times (1-p)^{n-2}$. And how many of these cases we have? It's the number of combinations we can have when we select $2$ items out of $n$. This is written as $n \choose 2$.

More generally the probability of exactly $i$ events happening is:
$$\binom{n}{i}\times p^i\times (1-p)^{n-i}$$

So your sum (to calculate that any event is happening) is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}\times p^i\times (1-p)^{n-i}$$

If this sum started from index $0$ then it would be equal to $1$ (proof using the binomial expansion formula). So our sum is $1 - (\text{term indexed 0}) = 1-(1-p)^n$

Comment: What about if the events did not have the same probability of occurring? Would that be possible to compute?

Comment: @TiffanyButterfly look at the simple way to compute this probability (the one I mention first). What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, I got it once I looked at this thread. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396214/probability-of-at-least-n-events-occuring , its pretty messy but makes sense